# Solving hang on wxWidgets radio button GetValue() call

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I'm currently using wxWidgets to create a GUI which can essentially operate in two modes, and I'm letting the user choose which one with a pair of radio buttons.  However, at the bifurcation point when the program decides which mode to use, the program hangs indefinitely while waiting for a `wxRadioButton` object's `GetValue()` function to return.

While debugging inside of the `GetValue()` function, I can see that the `m_isChecked` parameter (the `bool` that the function returns to indicate the state of the radio button) is defined and has the correct value, but the function attempts to make an assertion (a concept which I'm a bit shaky on, at best) before returning the value.  The (short) code is as follows:

```
bool wxRadioButton::GetValue() const
{
    wxASSERT_MSG( m_isChecked ==
                (::SendMessage(GetHwnd(), BM_GETCHECK, 0, 0L) != 0),
                wxT("wxRadioButton::m_isChecked is out of sync?") );

    return m_isChecked;
}
```

As far as I can tell, the `SendMessage()` function is causing the hang, a problem which others also seem to be having in different circumstances.  The very strange thing, however, is that I can execute the `GetValue()` function early in my code, consistently, without error (others had claimed a seemingly random factor in whether or not their radio buttons worked).  I don't know what could have significantly changed between then and the bifurcation point. Edit: I've tested the code, and it seems to work all the way until the program starts multi-threading, at which point the `GetValue()` function stops working.  Could that have something to do with the hanging?

My question is whether or not anyone has any insight into how to remove this hanging?  My last resort is to modify the wxWidgets code, but that just seems like a terrible idea.  Any thoughts would be GREATLY appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As the [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx) function,  it sends the specified message to a window or windows. The SendMessage function calls the window procedure for the specified window and does not return until the window procedure has processed the message.

So it means the function which handles the BM_GETCHECK message doesn't return, you should check that function first.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to find the function which handles the BM_GETCHECK message?  I didn't make it, and I think `wxWidgets` initializes by itself...probably with the help of Windows.  The strange thing is that it works when the code is initially run, but not later on.

Comment: That was the first thing that I tried, but it came up empty.  Perhaps there some obscure little library that's handling it, or something.  So, you think the problem is the function that's supposed to be handling that message?

Comment: What does GetHwnd() function return? This message suppose to be handled by this Window.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the assert isn't actually triggered and you simply missed the dialog box waiting for your input? This is the only explanation I see for the behaviour you observe.

We'd really need some [simple example reproducing the problem](http://sscce.org/) to tell you how can this happen if it's due to anything else because I had never seen this before (there have been problems with the standard `::IsDialogMessage()` Windows function entering an infinite loop when radio buttons are involved, but, first, they were fixed and, second, the problem was never in `BM_GETCHECK` in the first place).

Comment: I just checked, and I didn't miss any dialogues as far as I can tell.  I'm definitely waiting on the assert, and I assume that I'm waiting on the SendMessage, because my code just stops moving right after it, I can't get to the next line of code. I'll try to make some short example code, but I mostly hoping that someone had had a similar problem before.